# nodejs + connect - writeHead not working

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

I am writing simple applicaton and on server side I am using `noodejs` with `connect` framework.

Now in one of my middlewares I had something like this:

```
response.writeHead(302,{'Location': "/",'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
response.end();
```

now I observed that status code and headers of response were not being set correctly but  when I added

```
response.statusCode = 302;
response.setHeader('Location', "/");
response.end();
```

insted of my old oneliner with `writeHead` everything seems to work fine.

Am I misusing `writeHead` function or is it broken in my version of node (v0.10.15)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think that I found the answer, in my middleware stack I added `connect-livereload` plugin and when in my Webstorm I debugged writeHead function, I can see just by the looking at the code:

```
res.writeHead = function() {};
```

that it does nothing, and that is why nothing was set in the response.

I don't know if it is a bug in `connect-livereload` or not.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to do `response.end();` in the second snippet.

Comment: It is implicit so to speak, I wrote that I swapped oneliner for those two calls, but I will add `response.end()` invocation to the snippet ( and it is in my normal code) so this is not the case.

Comment: In the first case, node generates the response that has status code set to 200 (insted of 302) and does not have `Location` and `Content-Type` headers set. It behaves like it ignores my calls to `writeHead` method.

Comment: I was thinking - maybe connect swaps nornal `writeHead` function for some other one that takes different parameters?

Comment: I tested the exact same code and produced same result (with extra header of content-type). Maybe you opened the redirected link ?

Comment: I don't think that is the case, firstly I am not getting any redirection in the first case, also when I view network traffic in firebug I can see that my request got answer with 200 and it does not contain those headers set. I stumbled upon something like https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/683 but here it says that the issue should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of connect-livereload. This was actually a bug, but is now fixed with the latest version (0.3.1). Sorry for the inconvenience it caused.